# Can I disconnect the sensor on my overhead door and still have the door work with an opener?

Tags: garage-door-opener

Can I disconnect the floor sensor on my overhead door and still have it work with a remote and wall opener?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Why do you want to do this? Have you tried? What's the make/model of the opener, and what does the manual say?

Comment: Simple disconnection would not work. It may be possible to defeat the system which depends on a functioning floor sensor, but it would probably require some considerable intervention. This would no doubt offer your homeowner's insurance company grounds for non payment should a harmful event occur. Would also violate city codes. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just *why* do you want to do this? This sounds like a squishy recipe if you ask me...